# Can scraping be applied to this page which is actively recalculating?

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I would like to grab satellite positions from the page(s) below, but I'm not sure if scraping is appropriate because the page appears to be updating itself every second using some internal code (it keeps updating after I disconnect from the internet). Background information can be found in my question at Space Stackexchange: [A nicer way to download the positions of the Orbcomm-2 satellites](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13217/12102).

I need a "snapshot" of four items **simultaneously**:

- UTC time
- latitude
- longitude
- altitude

Right now I use screen shots and manual typing. Since these values are being updated by the page - is conventional web-scraping going to work here? I found a "screen-scraping" tag, should I try to learn about that instead?

I'm looking for the simplest solution to get those four values, I wonder if I can just use `urllib` or `urllib2` and avoid installing something new?

example page: http://www.satview.org/?sat_id=41186U I need to do 41179U through 41189U (the eleven Orbcomm-2 satellites that SpaceX just put in orbit)

[image: highlighted screen shot of satview.org]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to fire up a *real browser* and continuously poll the position in an endless loop:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.satview.org/?sat_id=41186U")


while True:
    location = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#sat_latlon .texto_track2").text
    latitude, longitude = location.split("\n")[:2]

    print(latitude, longitude)

    time.sleep(1)
```

Sample output:

```
(u'-16.57', u'66.63')
(u'-16.61', u'66.67')
...
```

Here we are using [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) and Firefox - there are multiple drivers for different browsers including headless, like [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/).

Comment: @uhoh yeah, selenium is installed via `pip install selenium`, but it would actually use real browsers. The browsers can be remote or headless. Note that If you would use `Chrome`, you would need a `chromedriver`. I would suggest start with regular Firefox (install it on your OSX if it's not there). Hope that helps.

Comment: OK I'm going to look for some help locally to try and understand what you are saying, since it's obviously going to be extremely useful to know how to do this!! In the mean time, I'll try to install selenium and test the script you've provided. Thanks!

Comment: ...and timing? Is Selenium "running" the pages javascript in the background and updating every second? If I'm not careful, I might occasionally get a mismatch of 1 second between different fields? I'll look for some kind of test.

Comment: @uhoh everything would work the way you see it in your browser, since this is, the same browser. I think you are asking about  the `find_*` methods that selenium issues to locate elements on a page. Every `find_*` call this is actually a JSON wire webdriver protocol request. And, if you would have, say, one `find_*` call for the UTC time and the other for the location, I think, in theory you may get the UTC time -> location sync problems..but, yeah, we need to test that. Let me know if you are still on track of what I'm trying to say. Thanks!

Comment: I've done pip install selenium in a virtual environment, and downloaded and installed Firefox. Each took about two minutes. I then typed your script line-by-line in a terminal and it immediately works!! **WOW!!!** Thank you @alecxe!

Comment: for completeness, the altitude comes from the third item in `"#sat_azel .texto_track2"`, and the displayed time appears to be in synch with my computers system time. It is probably the argument of the code which calculates the data, rather than the result of the calculation.

Comment: I tried a complete script, and I'm getting errors about half the time - I've edited the question to include both...

Comment: @uhoh thanks for trying that out. I think this happens when there is a page update between `find` and `getText` webdriver commands - interesting use case you have here! I think, you can just use `try/except` to catch stale element reference errors and continue the loop or retry the find+get text. Let me know if you need further help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

no need to scrape.  Just look at the source html of that page and copy/paste the javascript code.  None of the positions are fetched remotely...they're all calculated on the fly in the page.  So just grab the code and run it yourself!

Comment: That would be great if I could, but I'm looking for a solution using Python.

Answer (score 1):

Space-Track.org's REST API seems built to handle this type of request.  Once you have an account there, you can even download a sample script (updated here) to download TLES:

```
# STTest.py
#
# Simple Python app to extract resident space object history data from www.space-track.org into a spreadsheet
# (prior to executing, register for a free personal account at https://www.space-track.org/auth/createAccount)
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation,
# either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY;
# without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
# See the GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# For full licencing terms, please refer to the GNU General Public License (gpl-3_0.txt) distributed with this release,
# or see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html.

import requests
import json
import xlsxwriter
import time
import datetime
import getpass
import sys

class MyError(Exception):
    def __init___(self, args):
        Exception.__init__(self, "my exception was raised with arguments {0}".format(args))
        self.args = args

# See https://www.space-track.org/documentation for details on REST queries
# "Find Starlinks" query finds all satellites w/ NORAD_CAT_ID > 40000 & OBJECT_NAME matching STARLINK*, 1 line per sat;
# the "OMM Starlink" query gets all Orbital Mean-Elements Messages (OMM) for a specific NORAD_CAT_ID in JSON format.

uriBase = "https://www.space-track.org"
requestLogin = "/ajaxauth/login"
requestCmdAction = "/basicspacedata/query"
requestFindStarlinks = "/class/tle_latest/NORAD_CAT_ID/>40000/ORDINAL/1/OBJECT_NAME/STARLINK~~/format/json/orderby/NORAD_CAT_ID%20asc"
requestOMMStarlink1 = "/class/omm/NORAD_CAT_ID/"
requestOMMStarlink2 = "/orderby/EPOCH%20asc/format/json"

# Parameters to derive apoapsis and periapsis from mean motion (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_motion)
GM = 398600441800000.0
GM13 = GM ** (1.0 / 3.0)
MRAD = 6378.137
PI = 3.14159265358979
TPI86 = 2.0 * PI / 86400.0

# Log in to personal account obtained by registering for free at https://www.space-track.org/auth/createAccount
print('\nEnter your personal Space-Track.org username (usually your email address for registration):  ')
configUsr = input()
print('Username capture complete.\n')
configPwd = getpass.getpass(prompt='Securely enter your Space-Track.org password (minimum of 15 characters):  ')
# Excel Output file name - e.g. starlink-track.xlsx (note: make it an .xlsx file)
configOut = 'STText.xslx'
siteCred = {'identity': configUsr, 'password': configPwd}

# User xlsxwriter package to write the .xlsx file
print('Creating Microsoft Excel (.xlsx) file to contain outputs...')
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(configOut)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
z0_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0'})
z1_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.0'})
z2_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
z3_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.000'})

# write the headers on the spreadsheet
print('Starting to write outputs to Excel file create...')
now = datetime.datetime.now()
nowStr = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
worksheet.write('A1', 'Starlink data from' + uriBase + " on " + nowStr)
worksheet.write('A3', 'NORAD_CAT_ID')
worksheet.write('B3', 'SATNAME')
worksheet.write('C3', 'EPOCH')
worksheet.write('D3', 'Orb')
worksheet.write('E3', 'Inc')
worksheet.write('F3', 'Ecc')
worksheet.write('G3', 'MnM')
worksheet.write('H3', 'ApA')
worksheet.write('I3', 'PeA')
worksheet.write('J3', 'AvA')
worksheet.write('K3', 'LAN')
worksheet.write('L3', 'AgP')
worksheet.write('M3', 'MnA')
worksheet.write('N3', 'SMa')
worksheet.write('O3', 'T')
worksheet.write('P3', 'Vel')
wsline = 3


def countdown(t, step=1, msg='Sleeping...'):  # in seconds
    pad_str = ' ' * len('%d' % step)
    for i in range(t, 0, -step):
        sys.stdout.write('{} for the next {} seconds {}\r'.format(msg, i, pad_str))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(step)
    print('Done {} for {} seconds!  {}'.format(msg, t, pad_str))

# use requests package to drive the RESTful session with space-track.org
print('Interfacing with SpaceTrack.org to obtain data...')
with requests.Session() as session:

    # Need to log in first. NOTE:  we get a 200 to say the web site got the data, not that we are logged in.
    resp = session.post(uriBase + requestLogin, data=siteCred)
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        raise MyError(resp, "POST fail on login.")

    # This query picks up all Starlink satellites from the catalog. NOTE: a 401 failure shows you have bad credentials.
    resp = session.get(uriBase + requestCmdAction + requestFindStarlinks)
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        print(resp)
        raise MyError(resp, "GET fail on request for resident space objects.")

    # Use json package to break json-formatted response into a Python structure (a list of dictionaries)
    retData = json.loads(resp.text)
    satCount = len(retData)
    satIds = []
    for e in retData:
        # each e describes the latest elements for one resident space object. We just need the NORAD_CAT_ID...
        catId = e['NORAD_CAT_ID']
        satIds.append(catId)

    # Using our new list of resident space object NORAD_CAT_IDs, we can now get the OMM message
    maxs = 1 # counter for number of sessions we have established without a pause in querying space-track.org
    for s in satIds:
        resp = session.get(uriBase + requestCmdAction + requestOMMStarlink1 + s + requestOMMStarlink2)
        if resp.status_code != 200:
            # If you are getting error 500's here, its probably the rate throttle on the site (20/min and 200/hr)
            # wait a while and retry
            print(resp)
            raise MyError(resp, "GET fail on request for resident space object number " + s + '.')

        # the data here can be quite large, as it's all the elements for every entry for one resident space object
        retData = json.loads(resp.text)
        for e in retData:
            # each element is one reading of the orbital elements for one resident space object
            print("Scanning satellite " + e['OBJECT_NAME'] + " at epoch " + e['EPOCH'] + '...')
            mmoti = float(e['MEAN_MOTION'])
            ecc = float(e['ECCENTRICITY'])
            worksheet.write(wsline, 0, int(e['NORAD_CAT_ID']))
            worksheet.write(wsline, 1, e['OBJECT_NAME'])
            worksheet.write(wsline, 2, e['EPOCH'])
            worksheet.write(wsline, 3, float(e['REV_AT_EPOCH']))
            worksheet.write(wsline, 4, float(e['INCLINATION']), z1_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 5, ecc, z3_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 6, mmoti, z1_format)
            # do some ninja-fu to flip Mean Motion into Apoapsis and Periapsis, and to get orbital period and velocity
            sma = GM13 / ((TPI86 * mmoti) ** (2.0 / 3.0)) / 1000.0
            apo = sma * (1.0 + ecc) - MRAD
            per = sma * (1.0 - ecc) - MRAD
            smak = sma * 1000.0
            orbT = 2.0 * PI * ((smak ** 3.0) / GM) ** (0.5)
            orbV = (GM / smak) ** (0.5)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 7, apo, z1_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 8, per, z1_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 9, (apo + per) / 2.0, z1_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 10, float(e['RA_OF_ASC_NODE']), z1_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 11, float(e['ARG_OF_PERICENTER']), z1_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 12, float(e['MEAN_ANOMALY']), z1_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 13, sma, z1_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 14, orbT, z0_format)
            worksheet.write(wsline, 15, orbV, z0_format)
            wsline = wsline + 1
        maxs = maxs + 1
        print(str(maxs))
        if maxs > 18:
            print('\nSnoozing for 60 secs for rate limit reasons (max 20/min and 200/hr).')
            countdown(60)
            maxs = 1
    session.close()
workbook.close()
print('\nCompleted session.')
```

Comment: I plan to modify this script to look only for a particular set of resident space objects by passing it a dictionary of the catalog identifiers.  Despite the 60-second snooze, Space-Track.org keeps blocking my entire domain (based on IP address) after I get that far and I cannot pick up where I left off.  I am currently waiting for it to be unblocked again...I think Space-Track.org suspects I am hacking them. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I remember this moment, I was so excited by SpaceX's first launch and deployment of the ten Orbcomm satellites and wanted to understand how they would then move away from each other and eventually take up their final orbits. I didn't even know what a TLE was. This project got me interested in really learning some python and joining Space SE (which I see you've found as well). These days I do [stuff like this](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37454/12102) but I use the Space-Track GUI manually so I'm really excited to see how to use their API *thanks!*